# excel clear dependent dropdownlist vba

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu, refresh

After all, I already have the dropdownlists, the dependencies etc. and it works well, ALSO I have a vba code that, when the user change one value from the dropdownlist parent, the dependence clear their contents. BUT

That only works with that cell...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C2")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("D2").ClearContents
End If
End Sub
```

Obviusly because I'm tellin vba that only C2 & D2, but What I want it's that somebody would help to figure it out how to make it the entire column, not just that specific cell, like (column - 1 ) or something... because if I copy paste those dropdownlists only works in the first one cause that is specified...

Anybody? Any ideas? please.

Here there are some pics
[image]

[image]

In the pictures above, the dropdownlists work only in that specific cell, I tried what Hol told me with the function Cells(row index,columnIndex) but I need a for or something like that  isn't it ? This is the first thing I'm doing in vba so I dont have a clue and I'm looking for examples and then trying, it takes too long hahaha, 
I've already tried instead of "C2" , Column(3) and in D2 Column(4) but I have an error in the conditional `If Not Intersect(Target, Range(Column(3))) Is Nothing Then`

Comment: With what criteria do you determine C2 and D2? What do you mean with (column-1)? What column? You do not need to write "C2". You can also use the `Cells` function `Cells(<row>,<column>)` which allow you mathematics. Or you can use `Target.Offset(0,-1)`

Comment: Hey hol, thanks for answering, what I meant with C2 & D2 it's where I have my dropdownlists and how i managed to work, but I need the column with dropdownlists and obviously only works in C2 and in D2, by Column -1, I meant like in array in other language you make something like column.length -1 hahaha just for saying but turned out confusing SORRY, I'll try what u suggest thank u

Comment: @Raf0c, would be better to see a schema or a screen shot of what you have or what you need. After that we could try to provide more accurate help.

Comment: @Raf0c, to make it clear, you want to work it in pairs- C2 clear D2, C3 clear D3, C4 >>D4, and so on...??

Comment: umm Yes please ! the user will put more than one row and D2 depends of the selection of C2 ...and so on...  so I think need what u said... :D

Comment: so, see my answer for what you need...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand you want your macro to works in pairs: any change in C column (as of 2nd row bottom direction) will clear cell in D column in the same row. If so the following code does the trick.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If Target.Column = 3 Then
    Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 .. but you should really disable Events when making further changes.